# Comparar linhas de um arquivo com dados de uma planilha

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Sou novo no Python e estou com um problema que tá me tirando do serio...

É o seguinte, quero pegar as *strings* de um arquivo e comparar os elementos dela com as frases escritas nas planilhas do meu arquivo `.xlsx`.

Só que as *strings* do arquivo irão ter o que está escrito na planilha mais alguns códigos.

Quero que o programa faça o seguinte: Se na linha do arquivo tem o que esta na coluna que estou percorrendo faça a instrução `else`, pule para a próxima linha.

Segue o código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import xlrd

arquivo = open("/home/weslei/Documentos/t.txt", "r")
read = arquivo.readlines()

xls = xlrd.open_workbook('chips.xlsx')
plan = xls.sheets()[0]
b =  plan.col(0)

for i in read:
   for n in b:
       if n == i[20:57]:
           print "instrucao"
       else:
           print "next"
```

O arquivo que eu estou lendo tem esse conteúdo:

```
|7891515433963     |AMENDOIM SEM PELE MANIX 40G          |UN|34119/6|AF  4,9900|
|7897846301872     |AREIA HIG ABSORCAT             4KG   |UN|32306/2|AF  7,9900|
|7898948468012     |ARROZ CARRIJO TIPO1            5KG   |UN|32471/7|AF 13,8000|
|7896290300974     |ARROZ PRATO FINO ORGAN INTEG 1K UN   |UN|33908/7|AF 14,9500|
|7896290300318     |ARROZ PRATO FINO PARBOLIZADO   2KG   |UN|32034/4|AF  8,7500|
|7896290300295     |ARROZ PRATO FINO PARBOLIZADO 1K UN   |UN|32185/3|AF  4,3900|
|0000000000000     |ARROZ PRATO RICO AGULINHA 5KG        |UN|34335/0|AF  0,0000|
```

E a planilha:

```
ELMA CHIPS  
AMENDOIM SEM PELE MANIX 40G 1,79
BACONZITOS 55G  3,68
*BACONZITOS 110G    6,15
*BATATA SENSAÇÃO FG.GRELH. 90G  6,15
*CEBOLITOS 60G  3,68
*CEBOLITOS ASSADO 110G/120G 6,49
*CHEETOS 51G/ 55G/57G/59G/61G    2,49 
*CHEETOS  130G/150G/160G    6,28
*DEMONTÃO RUFLES BACON. 75G 4,45
*DORITOS 55G    3,65
*DORITOS QUEIJO 96G/110G/100G   6,25
*DORITOS QUEIJO NACHO 167GR 9,98
*DORITOS  200G/220G 9,98
*FANDANGOS 63G   2,45 
*FANDANGOS PRESUNTO/QUEIJO 175G 6,25
*FANDANGOS PRESUNTO 164GR   6,25
*PANETINI PRESUNTO / QUEIJO 40G 1,89
*PINGO D'OURO 65G   2,99
*PINGO D'OURO 90G   3,68
*RUFFLES 90G/100G   6,15
RUFFLES 96GR    6,15
*RUFFLES 175G    9,98 
*RUFFLES 57/50G  3,50 
*SALGADINHOS TORCIDA 60/50G 1,75
```

**Detalhe**: O programa emite a saída das colunas como `text:u'*SALGADINHOS TORCIDA 60/50G'`, todas as colunas saem com o `text:u`, causando o erro na iteração pq no arquivo não tem `text:u`.

Comment: Qual a versão do Python? e como você está emitindo a saída?

Comment: Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quero que o programa faça o seguinte: Se na linha do arquivo tem o que esta na coluna que estou percorrendo: faça a instrução `else`: pule para a próxima linha.

Para passar para a próxima iteração você pode usar o [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue). Não seria mais prático verificar se o conteúdo da coluna está presente na linha e usar o `continue`?

> O programa emite a saída das colunas como `text:u'*SALGADINHOS TORCIDA 60/50G'` todas as colunas saem com o `text:u`, causando o erro na iteração pq no arquivo não tem `text:u`.

Você deve estar usando o Python *2.x*, o prefixo `u` indica que trata-se de uma *string* [**Unicode**](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Você pode usar a função [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) para retornar uma *string* ou codificar para UTF-8 com o a função [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), por exemplo: `nome_da_variavel.encode('utf-8')`.

Duas sugestões:

- Use o [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) quando abrir o arquivo, assim o identificador do arquivo será fechado automaticamente após o uso. É semelhante ao [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx) do C#.
- Ao invés de comparar `if n == i[20:57]`, você pode fazer `if n in i`.

O código pode ficar parecido com isto (testei no Python 3, pode ser um pouco diferente no Python 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('t.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    xls = xlrd.open_workbook('chips.xlsx')

    planilha = xls.sheets()[0]
    coluna = planilha.col(0)

    for linha in arquivo:
        linha = linha.rstrip() # Para remover a quebra de linha

        for item in coluna:
            if item.value in linha:
                print ("Item encontrado: ", item)
                # Aqui você pode usar o "continue" para pular para o próximo item
```

Comment: e ai cara, obrigado pela dica acho que vou seguir pelo in mesmo, o codigo retornou esse erro

Comment: File "t.py", line 17, in <module>
    if item in linha:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Cell

Comment: vou tentar converter o "item" para str (pois e o mesmo tipo que esta no arquivo comparado) e mando o retorno aqui

Comment: @Safadão Disponha. Tente assim `if item.value in linha:`. Não tenho muita experiência com o `xlrd`, mas veja se desse modo funciona.

Comment: aae irmao deu certo o item.value, saida :

Comment: ('Item encontrado: ', text:u'AMENDOIM SEM PELE MANIX 40G')

Comment: brigadão precisar pode chamar ajudou dmss vlw